# Tableau Server Client (TSC) to Fetch Extracts Only

Tags: python, tableau-api

I would like to fetch only those `datasources` which are of type: **Extract**, and **skip** on the **Live** Data Sources. I am using `tableauserverclient` python library.

I have found code online to filter on the basis of data source name but I want to filter on the basis of data source type. Below is the code to filer on data source name:

```
req_option = TSC.RequestOptions() 
req_option.filter.add(TSC.Filter(TSC.RequestOptions.Field.Name,
                             TSC.RequestOptions.Operator.Equals,
                             'Superstore'))                           
datasources = server.datasources.get(req_option)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, there is no way to filter on source type in the req_options. These are the items you can filter on in req_options:

```
For the above endpoints, you can filter or sort on the following fields:

    CreatedAt
    LastLogin
    Name
    OwnerName
    SiteRole
    Tags
    UpdatedAt
```

[docs](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/filter-sort)

There is a `has_extracts` attribute you can use after you pull all data sources though.

Try this code:

```
with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    # get all projects on site
    all_project_items, pagination_item = server.datasources.get()
    for x in all_project_items:
        if x.has_extracts:
            print(x.name, x.id, x.project_name, x.has_extracts)
```

Comment: Yes, we can filter after fetching all of the data sources. Thanks for the answer though. I guess this is the only solution.